# Easiest way (which is also best practice) to make div elements move down when viewing on mobile/tablet/lower screen sizes

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

So I am trying to create a website and currently have a side section and the main body to the right of that. What is the best way to make the right main body of text move down below the side section so when viewing on smaller devices (mobile tablet etc).

so essentially keep div 2 where it is and move divs 6 + 8 + 9 + 10 down below 2

Here is what I have so far:

```
     <div class="1">
        <div class="2">
          <div class="3">
            <img src="" />
          </div>

          <div class="4">
            <h1>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </h1>
          </div>

          <div class="5">
            <h1>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="6">              
            <h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            <br />
            <br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            <br />
            <br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
           </h1>
        </div>

        <div class="8">
          <h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
     </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="9"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>

    <div class="10"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
    </div>
    </div>






And here is my css


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #BBBDC0;
}

.1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  margin: 10%;

}

.2{
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 7 / 2;
}

.6{
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 6;
}

.8{
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 5 / 6;
}

.9{
  grid-area: 5 / 2 / 7 / 6;
}

.10{
  grid-area: 7 / 2 / 8 / 5;
}

.2,
.6,
.8,
.9,
.10{
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I'm unsure which is the best way to do about this, would it be media queries? if so what is the best way to do? if not what are some other possibilities one could consider? (I renamed my divs to numbers as i wanted to keep them private for the time being)

Thanks to any contribution in advance anything is a help :)

Comment: CSS class names can't start with a digit.  So, before you try to get this working, you'll want to fix that.  (Could be as simple as renaming, for example, the class "2" to c2".  But as written your code won't work, at least not in a cross-browser way.

Comment: Yeah the class names were changed to the numbers they are now to hid some details I don’t want to be public as of now :)

Comment: But other than that, how else would the code not work? And how would it work in a cross browser way? Thanks

Comment: what I mean is, some browsers may be lenient and okay with class names that start with numerals (or not, I just don't know), but it's not a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using flex, you can order your elements however you wish. Combine this with media responsive CSS selector such as `@media only screen and (max-width: XXXpx){}`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items